# Made a program that spans a few classes for the first time but I am having issues with function calls.

Tags: c++, oop, console-application

I have made a little shop keeper program that allows a player to buy items from said shop keeper and stores the items in the players inventory. I am using OOP techniques for the first time and I have run into an issue that I am unable to resolve.

The issue I am having is in 'ShopKeeper.cpp', 'PurchaseItem' the items are not adding to the players inventory. There is something wrong with the function calls that I am doing. But if I were to call 'Player.AddItem()' in main, it works correctly. From my understanding, the way I have organised my code is correct? I feel that it is most readable - to me at least - though feel free to say not.

Here is the code I have so far. Sorry about the code being very long I am not sure if there is a limit to how much you can paste onto here but I thought it was best to show it all.

Thank you so much in advance.

**Main**

```
// Shop.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "ShopKeeper.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    Player player; //The player
    ShopKeeper shopKeeper; //The shop keeper

    int responce; //Menu navigation
    std::cout << "Greetings " << player.GetName() << ". Feel free to browse my wares." << "\n";
    std::cout << "1: Purchase Items. 2: Sell Items. 3: List Your Items. 4: Show Gold. 5: Exit" << "\n";

    do
    {
        std::cin >> responce;

        switch (responce)
        {
        case 1:
            shopKeeper.PurchaseItem();
            break;

        case 2:
            shopKeeper.SellItem();
            break;

        case 3:
            player.ListInventory();
            break;

        case 4:
            std::cout << "You have " << player.GetGold() << " gold coins." << "\n";
            break;

        case 5:
            std::cout << "Thank you for shopping." << "\n";
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "Please enter valid data." << "\n";
            std::cout << "1: Purchase Items. 2: Sell Items. 3: List Your Items. 4: Show Gold. 5: Exit" << "\n";
        }
    } while (responce != 5);

    /*
    //This works
    player.AddItem("Mace", 30);
    player.ListInventory();
    std::cout << player.GetGold();
    */

    //Keep window open
    std::string barn;
    std::cin >> barn;

    return 0;
}
```

**ShopKeeper.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class ShopKeeper
{
private: 



public:
    void PurchaseItem(); //Shop keeper has player buy items from them
    void SellItem(); //Shop keeper sells item to player

    ShopKeeper();
    ~ShopKeeper();

};
```

**ShopKeeper.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ShopKeeper.h"
#include "Player.h"

#include <iostream>

//Player purchases item from shop keeper
void ShopKeeper::PurchaseItem()
{
    Player player;

    int responce = 0; //Menu navigation
    std::cout << "1: Mace - 30 gold. 2: Bow - 50 gold. 3: Boots - 10 gold. 4: Bearskin - 75 gold. 5: Helmet - 25 gold." << "\n";

    do
    {
        std::cin >> responce;

        switch (responce)
        {
        case 1:
            player.AddItem("Mace", 30);
            break;

        case 2:
            player.AddItem("Bow", 50);
            break;

        case 3:
            player.AddItem("Boots", 10);
            break;

        case 4:
            player.AddItem("Bearskin", 75);
            break;

        case 5:
            player.AddItem("Helmet", 25);
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "Please enter valid data." << "\n";
            std::cout << "1: Mace - 30 gold. 2: Bow - 50 gold. 3: Boots - 10 gold. 4: Bearskin - 75 gold. 5: Helmet - 25 gold." << "\n";
        }
    } while (responce > 5 || responce < 1);

}

//Shop keeper sells item to player
void ShopKeeper::SellItem()
{
    Player player;
    int responce = 0;
    player.ListInventory();

    switch (responce)
    {
    case 1:
        player.SellItem(0, 20);
        break;

    case 2:
        player.SellItem(1, 20);
        break;

    case 3:
        player.SellItem(2, 20);
        break;

    case 4: 
        player.SellItem(3, 20);
        break;

    case 5:
        player.SellItem(4, 20);
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Please enter valid data." << "\n";
        player.ListInventory();
    }
}

ShopKeeper::ShopKeeper()
{
}


ShopKeeper::~ShopKeeper()
{
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

class Player
{
private:
    const int maxNumbItems = 5; //Maximum number of items that inventory can store

    int goldCoins = 150, //Amount of gold coins the player has
        numbOfItems = 0; //Number of con-current items player holds
    std::vector<std::string> inventory; //Players inventory
    std::string name = "Gorrex"; //Players name

public:
    std::string GetName(); //Get the players name
    std::string AddItem(std::string item, int itemPrice); // Add item to players inventory
    void Player::SellItem(int itemNum, int itemPrice); //Sell item 
    bool IsInventoryFull(); //Check to see if players inventory is full
    int InventoryCapacity(); //Get capacity of inventory
    int GetGold(); //Get players gold
    void ListInventory();


    Player();
    ~Player();
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Player.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

//Get the players name
std::string Player::GetName()
{
    return name;
}

//Add item to players inventory
std::string Player::AddItem(std::string item, int itemPrice)
{
    //Is players inventory not full?
    if (IsInventoryFull())
    {
        std::cout << "Inventory is full.";
    }

    else
    {
        //Can player afford item?
        if (goldCoins >= itemPrice)
        {
            goldCoins -= itemPrice;
            numbOfItems++;
            std::cout << "You have purchased " << item << "." << "\n";
            inventory.push_back(item); //Add item to inventory
            return item;
        }

        //If player cant afford item 
        else
        {
            std::cout << "You cannot afford this item." << "\n";
        }
    }
}

void Player::SellItem(int itemNum, int itemPrice)
{
    char responce;
    std::cout << "Are you sure you want to sell: " << inventory[itemNum] << "? 'y' - Yes. 'n' - No." << "\n";
    std::cin >> responce;

    switch (responce)
    {
    case 'y':
        numbOfItems++;
        goldCoins += itemPrice;
        inventory.erase(inventory.begin() + itemNum);
        break;

    case 'n':
        std::cout << "That is ok." << "\n"; 
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Please enter correct data." << "\n";
    }
}




//Check to see if players inventory is full
bool Player::IsInventoryFull()
{
    //If players inventory isnt full
    if (numbOfItems < maxNumbItems)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //If players inventory is full
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

//Return size of players inventory
int Player::InventoryCapacity()
{
    return inventory.size();
}

//Get the players gold
int Player::GetGold()
{
    return goldCoins;
}

//List the players inventory
void Player::ListInventory()
{
    int itemNumb = 0; //item number in menu

    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        itemNumb++;
        std::cout << itemNumb << ": " << inventory[i] << "\n";
    }

    /*  //If inventory is empty
    if (inventory.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "inventory is empty" << "\n";
    }*/

}

Player::Player()
{
}


Player::~Player()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Shopkeeper you are declaring a local instance of `Player` that goes away after the function call:

```
void ShopKeeper::PurchaseItem()
{
    Player player;
```

Make `PurchaseItem` accept a `Player& player` instead of declaring a local `Player`.

The same is true for `SellItem`. You need to specify who to sell to.

Then in your `main` you can say this:

```
switch (responce)
{
case 1:
   shopKeeper.PurchaseItem(player);
   break;

 case 2:
    shopKeeper.SellItem(player);
//...
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my issue. Do you know of any other improvements I could make to my code?

Comment: @RyanSwann: Well you probably want to make `Inventory` its own class. Then Player would `have a` instance of it. This allows you to make shopkeepers that have an inventory as well (eventually subclassing Player and Shopkeeper from the same base). Pricing items for a shopkeeper would be part of an economy system, but for now you could just hard-code item values. as a field on the item. Meaning `Item` would become its own class, with a name and a value.

Answer (score 2):

The `Player` in `ShopKeeper` is local to `ShopKeeper` and is unrelated to `Player` from `main`.

You have to pass `Player` to `ShopKeeper` methods.
You have several choice: pass it in constructor of `ShopKeeper`
or pass it by reference to method:

Replace

```
void ShopKeeper::PurchaseItem()
{
    Player player;
    // ...
```

By

```
void ShopKeeper::PurchaseItem(Player& player)
{
    // ...
```

and call it

```
shopKeeper.PurchaseItem(player);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my issue. Do you know of any other improvements I could make to my code?

Comment: As local improvements: add missing `const`, remove unneeded code as empty constructor/destructor.

Comment: As structural improvements: I would move some logic from `Player` to `ShopKeeper`, classes `Inventory`/`Item` make sense (and would simplify class Player). A class to handle question system to avoid those `switch case` should be good too.

Comment: Create unit tests should also be a good addition (and you have to manage a non interactive mode for that).